Problem about inputs (zones) of a security system
I have a couple of questions regarding home security control panels and PCB design that I hope someone can help me with.
First, I'm curious about the circuit and components used in the zones of a home security control panel, particularly how sensors connect to the microcontroller. What are the typical components involved, and how do they interact to ensure reliable performance in detecting security breaches?

Additionally, I’ve noticed that some PCBs utilize corrugated tracks instead of traditional straight traces. What is the purpose of using these corrugated tracks? Are there specific advantages they offer in terms of signal integrity or manufacturing?


Fyi those "corrugated" tracks are commonly called serpentines, meanders or accordions.

The only reason I  can think of to have them there is to use them as a crude current shunt.

I'm sure you can understand that this question reads like "Tell me how to break into security systems". People here may well suspect someone of the worst reasons for wanting to know and not want to participate. Either way, this is far too broad so VTC.

Alarms are a simple wire loop circuit.  when the loop is opened, the alarm is triggered.

@Drew Motion detectors are being connected to this inputs. is it reasonable to use such tracks?

@TonyM  I want to make one of them. which burglar seeks for components of a device?

Those serpentine tracks seemed to be all the rage in the early 2000’s. Supposedly the inductance helped with ESD protection. This seems to have been discounted and modern designs tend to avoid them. Signal integrity is not a consideration as the rate of change is slow.
Typically you’ll see a RC filter, transzorbs and/or varistor into something like a 4051 multiplexer ic to a resistor divider then to the ADC input on the microcontroller. Sometimes a ratiometric measurement technique is used when the sensor supply voltage (nominally 12V but varies due to battery charging or running on battery alone). This involves a suitably protected 12V input with similar filtering to the zone input and scaled to be the Vref for the ADC. Otherwise you need to measure the 12V supply and use this to scale the zone input values.
The zone inputs generally detect four states - open, short, sealed, unsealed (alarm). The sensor generally comprises two resistors in series, with the detector switch (n/c) across one of the resistors. Each alarm panel manufacturer seem to have their own standard for resistor values - 2k2,4k7 and 10k seem to be popular. It is up to your code in the microcontroller to measure the resistance, determine which of the four states it is in and some debounce/filtering to eliminate false alarms. 50 to 200ms are common values.
Since the detector wires are generally many metres long, they act as antennas for nearby lightning strikes, so you really need some good ESD protection and careful pcb layout. The magnetic field can introduce significant current into the wires.
There’s plenty of low cost wireless PIR sensors available these days that make your zone inputs obsolete and eliminate a source of ESD. Installation is easier as well. I’d be looking in that direction.
The zone input method and Weigand protocol for readers are so ancient but they still persist even though they are far from secure. Avoid where possible!
